# Effect size: difference between Cohen's d and Wilcoxon's r?

Tags: effect-size

In the simple case where I have N trials with mean result  $\mu$ and I want a measure of how on the whole they differ from a theoretical model of a normal distribution with mean 0 and standard deviation 1, is there actually a difference between Cohen's $d$ and Wilcoxon's $r$?

I'm getting

$d=\frac{\Delta\mu}{\sigma_{pooled}}$

Since we are comparing with planet Normal, $\sigma_{pooled}$ is $\sqrt{N}$, so we get

$d=\frac{\Delta\mu}{\sqrt{N}}$

which is also the definition of Wilcoxon's effect size statistic $r$.

And for that matter, these are also equal in this case to the combined $z$-score.

Or am I missing something here?

Essentially having tried hard to understand Cohen's $d$ and Wilcoxon's $r$, what I am suggesting is

- they are both standardised $z$-scores, and
- Wilcoxon's assumes that what you are comparing with is normal; Cohen's doesn't.

Is that right?

I have found a lot that's written about these statistics, but both seem to boil down to something that's so simple I'm worried I may have misunderstood something.

Comment: *"$\sigma_{pooled}$ is $\sqrt{N}$"* How is the population deviation equal to $\sqrt{n}$? What population do you consider and why does it's deviation change with the number of trials? What are these trials?

Comment: *"the definition of Wilcoxon's effect size statistic $r$."* Could you name and quote a reference that defines Wilcoxon's effect size statistic in that way.

Comment: Q1: the combined sd of N normal variables (0,1) is $\sqrt{N}$. Q4: the first one that came up on a DuckDuckGo [search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=wilcoxon%27s+effect+size+definition&t=h_&ia=web) on `wilcoxon's effect size definition`.

Comment: that search on duckduckgo can be different each time.

Comment: You are taking the standard deviation of the sum of N standard normal variables. Why? How is that related to Cohen's d?

Comment: Here's the URL that DDG listed first: [Wilcoxon Effect Size](https://rpkgs.datanovia.com/rstatix/reference/wilcox_effsize.html). What's at a web address might change, so here's what's there now: "_The effect size [Wilcoxon's] r is calculated as Z statistic divided by square root of the sample size (N) ($\frac{Z}{\sqrt{N}}$)._" I don't find your questions useful. There was little point in asking me to source a standard definition, or what my trials are (as if I actually have some). Please open a chat page if you wish to continue in this vein.

Comment: The questions are useful because you have a source that uses $Z/\sqrt{N}$ which is different from what you have in the question (It is not clear how $\Delta \mu$ is the same as the z-score $Z$) and also there are more different definitions of Wilcoxon's $r$ ...

Comment: ...these questions might not be useful for you but they are useful to someone like me who is trying to understand your question. (But sadly now I have lost my interest)

Comment: It's necessary (by design of the stackexchange paradigm) to either have a clear question or to close it. Sextus' points and questions on the whole seem pretty directly relevant to clarifying the question. Without such feedback, the question could be on hold waiting for it to be improved but you'd instead have to *guess* what needs to be fixed. If you guessed wrong, it would remain on hold. That seems like it would be less than productive.